# My <footer> will not stay at the bottom of the page

Tags: css, html

My `<footer>` tag will not seem to stay at the bottom of my page. I have tried several different techniques to fix it and none have worked.

I have included the link to my working site below.

http://stage.bmdigitalgroup.com/recipes.html

Comment: looks okay on my end. which browser are you using?

Comment: I may be blind, but the footer appears to remain in the same place for me upon clicking 'Recipes' (Running Google Chrome in Ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: Hmmm.. I am showing the same issue on all of my browsers. Here is a screen... http://i50.tinypic.com/29vjbbs.png

Comment: It's at the bottom for me (Firefox in Windows 7) until I zoom out, in which case it rides up to stay under the content. Have you tried the [Css Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you want to put your footer at bottom of the page i any resolution, if am i right than here is answer.

```
.footer {
position:absolute;
border:0px;
}
```

for more tips, tricks and tutorial visit - [blog.klassicweb.com](http://blog.klassicweb.com)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot, it looks like your monitor's height is larger than your website's content or you have zoomed out a lot, so what you're seeing is totally normal. In a smaller monitor it would look just fine. You could add a `min-height:` rule to your sites container so it pushes the footer down to the specified value, but you need to figure out a min-height that makes sense to you and your users.

If you really want to make the footer always stick to the bottom regardless of the monitor's height or zoom level, then you could add the following rules - just keep in mind that in a page where there isn't much content, you will end up forcing users to scroll down for no reason if they need to get to the footer:

```
/* 
 This rule is already in your stylesheet. 
 I added it here just for reference. 
*/
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

/* 
  This is the container that holds your whole site. 
  You should use an id like "#container" or "#site" so this rule 
  applies only to your site's main container. 
*/
.container_12 {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: To avoid scrolling down to footer if there isn't much content you should make space for footer. To do that you must give negative bottom margin to you div with content. On your site it will be
margin-bottom: -170px;